# Infragistics UltraTree print/preview with nodes that have formatted/markup text

Tags: printing, infragistics, ultratree

I'm trying to print/preview an Infragistics UltraTree (winform) (version 14.2) which has formatted/markup text

The nodes of the tree use Infragistics.Win.FormattedLinkLabel.UltraFormattedTextEditor 
with TreatValueAs = FormattedLinkLabel.TreatValueAs.FormattedText

On the screen the tree looks nice.  However when I use Infragistics.Win.Printing.UltraPrintPreviewDialog, the resulting tree displays each node with all of its markups.

```
<span style='color:Navy; font-size:11pt; font-weight:bold; '> The Node's Text  </span>
```

Is there a way to have the preview display the same way it looks on the screen?  That is instead of the above, display "The Node's Text", where this text is printed in 11pt and the text color is navy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guys at Infragistics said it is a bug in their control [here](https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/109860.aspx). However, they provided and work around. Add this event handler in form's constructor:

```
    this.ultraTreePrintDocument1.Tree = this.ultraTree1;
    this.ultraTreePrintDocument1.InitializeTree += UltraTreePrintDocument1_InitializeTree;
```

And then in InitializeTree add this code:

```
    private void UltraTreePrintDocument1_InitializeTree(object sender, InitializeTreeEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Control.Override.EditorComponent = new UltraFormattedTextEditor();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As @wnvko indicated, Infragistics acknowledges the bug which will be corrected in their next service release.  This is the statement I received from Infragistics:

> Issue "237272: EditorComponent is not taken into account when printing
>   the tree" has been fixed and verified by our Engineering Team in the
>   following versions . We are in the final stages of creating the
>   service release and expect to publish it according to following
>   schedule:
>
> http://www.infragistics.com/support/service-releases/